# Mounting CIFS using hostname doesn't work

Tags: linux, docker, cifs, docker-compose

This comes from an old suggestion https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/39250 on an issue. I am trying to mount a CIFS volume, config it via IP worked for me but when I try to config it using a hostname it doesn't work.

`CIFS=XX.XX.XX.XX`

```
  api:
    image: name-api:$TAG
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: cc-api
    volumes:
      - cifs:/usr/node/cifs
volumes:
  cifs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=$WSDLUSER,password=$WSDLPASS,rw,domain=domain.com,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,file_mode=0400,dir_mode=0500
      device: "\\\\${CIFS}\\documentation\\_shared\\pdfs”
```

When I try to change it to `CIFSDOMAIN=cifs.domain.com` I get an error during creation of volume `invalid argument`. So this should work:

```
volumes:
  cifs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: addr=cifs.domain.com,username=$WSDLUSER,password=$WSDLPASS,rw,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,file_mode=0400,dir_mode=0500
      device: "\\\\${CIFSDOMAIN}\\documentation\\_shared\\pdfs”
```

It has been tried with with `"//${CIFSDOMAIN}/documentation/_shared/pdfs”` too.

Is it likely that the kernel driver does not resolve hostnames? [This article](https://random.blackpacket.net/2021/01/10/docker-nfs-and-cifs-volumes.html) says that you need to use the IP address when doing CIFS mounts because docker does not use the same userland tools to do the mount, and will fail if a hostname is provided.

Inspecting the volume shows the mountpoint, looks correct to me

```
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "cc",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.4",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "cifs"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/cc_cifs/_data",
        "Name": "cc_cifs",
        "Options": {
            "device": "\\\\cifs.domain.com\\documentation\\_shared\\pdfs",
            "o": "addr=cifs.domain.com,username=XXXXX,password=YYYYY,rw,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,file_mode=0400,dir_mode=0500",
            "type": "cifs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
```

Also, contents of **/etc/hosts** is:

`XX.XX.XX.XX cifs cifs.domain.com`